# As a Theurgy wizard with the Life Domain, can I use the Preserve Life feature?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, wizard, unearthed-arcana, domains

If I choose the Theurgy subclass (from [Unearthed Arcana: Wizard Revisited](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/MJ320UAWizardVF2017.pdf)) as a wizard and pick the [Life Domain](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/cleric#LifeDomain) for my Divine Inspiration, will the Channel Divinity: Preserve Life feature work for me as well, then?

> You present your holy symbol and evoke healing energy that can restore a number of hit points equal to five times your cleric level.

It says cleric level, so I'm unsure.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE. Please take the [tour] to see how to get the most out of this Q&A site.  Thanks for your question, and have fun.

Answer (score 10):

### Use your Wizard (Theurge) level

The Channel Arcana feature at second level uses your wizard level.

> [Channel  Arcana](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/MJ320UAWizardVF2017.pdf)
>   At    2nd level,  you gain    the ability to  channel 
>   arcane    energy  directly    from    your    deity,  using   that    energy  to  fuel    magical effects.    You start   with two such   effects: Divine Arcana
>   **and the Channel Divinity option granted at  2nd level   by  your chosen domain**. You   employ that Channel Divinity    option  by  using your  Channel Arcana ability.

The channel divinity option that you chose, Preserve Life, is one of two ways for you to use your Channel Arcana option.  All Channel Arcana options are tied to your wizard level, and by selecting that option it becomes a wizard ability, not a cleric ability<sup>1</sup>.

(The need to use your holy symbol appears to remain, as this UA/Playtest article does not waive that requirement, however, it would be a fair ruling to sub in the arcane focus for holy symbol there ... work that out with your DM).

---

<sup>1</sup> If Theurge required multiclassing to cleric, it would say so.  It does not require that, thus the borrowed channel divinity becomes Channel Arcana and is based on the PC's level in the Theurge class: Wizard.

Comment: @Illbatting glad to be of help.

Comment: I agree this is the most sensible RAI interpretation, and indeed is what I've ruled for close to the same question for a Theurge PC at my table, but I can't see how the provided quote leads to your conclusion RAW. In particular I don't see how "All Channel Arcana options are tied to your wizard level" is supported.

Can you expand on what supports that idea?

Comment: @Vigil UA is play test material, so applying 'RAW' style literalism is category error. Since I did not declare "this is RAW" I fail to see grounds for objection.  It makes utterly not sense to fold channel divinity into Channel Arcana and not use the wizard level. If Theurge required multi-classing it would say so.  It does not, so we are left with using the wizard's class to apply to this Channel Arcana option.

Comment: @Vigil  The text states this:  *Channel Arcana At 2nd level, you gain the ability to channel arcane energy directly from your deity, using that energy to fuel magical effects. You start with two such effects: Divine Arcana and the Channel Divinity option granted at 2nd level by your chosen domain. You employ that Channel Divinity option by using your Channel Arcana ability. When you use your Channel Arcana, you  choose which effect to create. You must then finish a short or long rest to use your Channel 
Arcana again*

Comment: +1. Experience with what works is the right source of authority here.